# Is there a way to search and replace a regular expression in Google Docs spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, microsoft-excel, formulas, regex

The problem is that I entered a lot of formulas like `=round(x+y)` into a Google Docs  spreadsheet. Now I need them exported to MS Excel and the latter only accepts `=round(x+y,0)` as a valid format. Since the doc holds a few 10s of this format - any suggestion on how to convert these would be highly appreciated (like if it can be done in MS Excel that's OK as well).

What I was thinking was a awk script sort of thing: find all `round(*)` replace with round(*,0)... of course this will have to ignore all the `round(*,2)` that I also have.

Tried to use the find and replace menu but it doesn't find `round` at all (and believe me it is there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find them using find and replace if you go to view -> all formulas (ctrl+') and then do you "round( " find this will at least cut down on the manual labor of it all

I couldnt find a way (using find and replace to search for wild card value  though

EDIT:

Try out the script below
REF: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Docs/thread?tid=288d77c8c9ad7696&hl=en

```
function SearchReplaceInFormula() {

  var pattern = Browser.inputBox("Enter the search string:");
  var replacement = Browser.inputBox("Enter the replacement string:");
  if (pattern == "" && replacement == "")
  {
    Browser.msgBox("Nothing to search and or replace");
    return;
  }

  var formula = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getFormulaR1C1();
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var crows = range.getNumRows();
  var ccols = range.getNumColumns();

  var row = 0;
  for (row = 1; row <= crows; row++)
  {
       for (col=1; col <= ccols; col++)
       {
         var cell = range.getCell(row, col);
         var formula = cell.getFormula();
         var updated = formula;
         while(-1 != updated.indexOf(pattern))
         {
           updated = updated.replace(pattern, replacement);
         }
         if (formula != updated)
         {
           cell.setFormula(updated)
         }
       }
  }

  Browser.msgBox("Done replacing " + pattern + " with " + replacement);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution (not what I expected and not perfect - but gets the job done!). Would have given you two up votes for the tip in the beginning (view all formulas) but can only up vote once :-)

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

Find: `(.+)\)`
Replace with: `$1,0)`
Search: This sheet (or to suit)
Search using regular expressions
Also search within formulae
Replace all.